# Magento 1.7 backend display error

Tags: magento, admin, backend

I have a strange error on Magento 1.7.0.2:
After duplicating an other installation, i get an error regarding orders in backend.
I made a [screenshot](http://imageshack.us/a/img600/6584/errorys.png) that you can understand what i mean.

If i try to change an address, i get the error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in .../src/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Form/Address.php on line 160`

I don't get where this issue comes from, because files from a working copy are used.
The only difference is, that i didn't dump the complete database from the working copy, because i didn't want to have all of the products and customers.

Comment: It seems that the customer address attribute `country_id` is missing, can you check in the `eav_attribute` table if it is present ? And if so, if there is a corresponding row in the `customer_eav_attribute` table ?

Comment: Ok, the display issue is fixed because i forgot to dump customer_eav_attribute table. Thanks!
But the Fatal Error still occures. I have another issue described here, perhaps this has something to do with this Form/Address.php error too: [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/421431/)

Comment: Did you dump the `customer_form_attribute` table ?

Comment: Nah ... i didn't *rolleyes*
Thanks a alot, spend hours of finding the missing tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you correctly dumped all the needed customer and address tables. The only ones you should skip should be the ones beginning by `customer_address_entity_` or `customer_address_entity_` - the content of the other tables is required for the customer and address forms to work.